# Probability and Frequency

Tags: math, statistics, probability, frequency

I am in the process of creating a program and I have run into an issue that involves probability.  My question involves trying to predict a number using probability and frequency.  I have done plenty of research on this matter but could not find an example that suits my personal question.

**Question:** Does frequency affect probability?

Let's say for example, I am going to flip a coin 5 times.  My goal is to get heads every single time.  If I get heads the first time, does that lower the probability that I will get heads a second time?  Or, if I get heads four times in a row; does that lower the probability that I will get heads a fifth time?
Is it safer to say that I will have a higher chance of getting a tails the fifth time after previously getting four heads in a row?

Comment: This question is off topic on Stackoverflow because it's purely about maths

Comment: For example, [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/829899/147357) on [math.se], and probably many others.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about mathematics, not programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, each flip is independent of subsequent flips.  You can get X heads in a row and the probability of a fair coin coming up heads the next time is still 0.50.

You might want to read this:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21825/probability-over-multiple-blocks-of-events

Comment: Thank you! This cleared everything up

Answer (score 1):

Coin flips are [independent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)).  That is to say, past coin flips have no impact on future coin flips.  Assuming a fair coin, the probability of flipping a heads is 1/2 or 50%.  These odds stay the same irregardless of past flips.  If you flip a coin ten times and every time it lands heads, the next flip is still has 1/2 chance of landing heads.